# Why does the kernel strip \< and \> from strings

Tags: front-end, undocumented

The FE always passes strings to the kernel that look like:

```
"\"\<asdasd\>\""
```

And the \< and > get pruned out. We can simulate this for ourselves with:

```
"\"" <> "\\" <> "<" <> "asdasd" <> "\\" <> ">" <> "\"" // ToExpression

"asdasd"
```

Now it doesn't prune anything else, e.g. try:

```
"\"" <> "\\" <> "(" <> "asdasd" <> "\\" <> ")" <> "\"" // ToExpression

"\(asdasd\)"
```

So does it only strip those little angle brackets because the FE passes them? Or is there some other reason for it? And is it documented anywhere?